# Embedding SoundCloud player in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, soundcloud

Is it possible to embed a soundcloud player in an iOS app? I've been searching around and all I can find is Javascript API. Is the only way to accomplish this through a UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment we don't provide any player/streaming frameworks for cocoa,
so the UIWebbView is probably your best bet to embed the player in your app, although I'm not sure if it is actually able to fully support the widget.

Please let us know if it works out.

Comment: Embedding the player code into a UIWebView seems to be working :)

Comment: However, it's not that responsive through a webview.

Comment: Has there been any update to this question? Is there now a iOS framework that allows streaming tracks?